# TypeError missing argument?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've been sitting here running over some code I have to create for school (it's a search system) and I have been trying to fix this error for ages. Any help is greatly appreciated.

the code: (i know the indentation is wrong its just for the websites formatting)

```
class Main:
    list = []
    def __init__(self, item, term):
        self.item = item
        self.term = term
    def add(self, item):
        Main.list.append(self.item)
        print(Main.list)
    def search(self, term):
        print(self.term)
        if self.term in Main.list:
            print("item exists")
        else:
            print("no such thing")

def running():
    command = input("command?")
    if command == "/add":
        item = Main(input("item to add?     "))
        item.add(item)
        running()
    if command == "/search":
        searchTerm = Main(input("item to search for"))
        searchTerm.search(searchTerm)
        print(Main.list)

    running()
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/x/x/x/x.py", line 27, in <module>
    running()
  File "/x/x/x/x.py", line 19, in running
    item = Main(input("item to add?     "))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'term'
```

Comment: You’re not passing a `term` argument when you call `Main()`.

Comment: You have : `__init__(self, item, term):`. You are initializing with `Main(input("item to add?     "))` that is 1 string for item. You are missing the `term` argument  as indicated by the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of the `Main` class (i.e. the `__init__` method) requires two parameters. That means you cannot do just `Main(input("item to add?     "))`, which passes one parameter (the result of `input()` method, which returns a string).

You need `Main(input("item to add?     "), something_else)`, i.e. two parameters.

Comment: So could I literally just fill this space with "" or is this considered poor syntax?

Comment: You could. If you don't need it, it's better to remove it from so it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: So what would i need to remove here? just get rid of term from the __init__ method?

Comment: Yes, but you would also remove `self.term = term`. You also have to fix the contents of `add` and `search` methods. You probably want to access the parameters of the method. If yes, don't use `self.item` and `self.term` but just `item` and `term` (in these two methods).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the term to be filled only if you need it you can pass this to **init**:

```
def __init__(self, item, term=''):
```